# How can I use a shortcut to add a Markdown code block to the selection text in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on some documents in Microsoft Word and [Evernote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evernote), I need to convert the contents to Markdown and save to [Obsidian](https://www.marclittlemore.com/beginners-guide-note-taking-obsidian/).

I usually manually add a code block:

````
```python
import xxx
some_content = 'balabala'

more = ....
```
````

As you know, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd> is adding a comment to every line.

Is there a way to do the following

1. use the cursor to make a selection of text
2. hit a shortcut to wrap that text with

   ````
   ```language
   selected text
   ```
   ````

I have searched in Google, but nothing useful was found.

Comment: Do you want to add the current editor's language automatically and paste it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This key binding may help:

````
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i 1",  // or any other combo
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "```python\n$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\n```\n$0"
    }
  }
````

You can add a language selection:

````
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i 1",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "```${1|python,javascript|}\n$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\n```\n$0"
    }
  }
````

Comment: Thank you ! I would do a futher research of setting language automatically .